# List (ArrayList)Traversal in java

Tags: java, collections

example, suppose I have one list which contains 45 element so from which i need to create  sets of lists which contains 10 element means if main list has 45 elements then it will crate 4 sets of 10 elements and and 1 for 5 elements so finally I wil get 5 lists. ok so after creating lists i need to call one function. that function will called 5 times.

`1 set
call()
2 set
call()
3 set
call()

4 set
call()

5 set
call()`

can anyone please provide the solution..

Thanks in advance
vinod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build upon the answer from Deepak:

If you have a `List<?> list` and want to call function `call` with size 10 chunks you may use the following code:

```
for (int idx = 0; idx < list.size(); idx += 10) {
    List<?> subList = list.subList(idx, Math.min(list.size(), idx + 10));
    call(subList);
}
```

Comment: Make sure that you don't change the original list, or the sublists in the `call` method (or concurrently), else you'll get confusion.

Answer (score 1):

list.subList() function in java should do the trick

Comment: @Vinod.you could check out the logic provided from @Howard

Answer (score 1):

**[Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/)** has just the method for you:

[`Iterables.partition(Iterable<E>, size)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#partition%28java.lang.Iterable,%20int%29)

**Sample usage:**

```
List<String> list = // initialize List
for(List<String> subList : Iterables.partition(list, 10)){
    // do something with the list
}
```